# How to repeat variables twice in xargs

Tags: xargs

How can I make the second echo to echo out test in this example as well:

```
 echo test  | xargs -I {} echo {} && echo {}
```

Comment: `var=test & echo $var ...`

Comment: xargs -I {} var={} echo $var && echo $var That would give you: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 58):

Just write `{}` two times in your command. The following would work:

```
$ echo test | xargs -I {} echo {} {}
test test
```

---

Your problem is how the commands are *nested*. Lets look at this:

```
echo test | xargs -I {} echo {} && echo {}
```

*bash* will execute `echo test  | xargs -I {} echo {}`. If it runs successfully, `echo {}` is executed. To change the nesting, you could do something like this:

```
echo test | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} && echo {}"
```

However, you could get trouble because the approach might be prone to code injection. When "test" is substituted with shell code, it gets executed. Therefore, you should probably pass the input to the nested shell with arguments.

```
echo test | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "$1" && echo "$1"' sh {}
```

Comment: Note that you will get unexpected results in your last code if you have afile callod, literally, `$(rm -f *)`.  It's better to do `xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "$1" && echo "$1"' sh {}`

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks. I was aware of the problem but I could not think of a simple solution at that moment. I integrated your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: This is the real answer right here. If all you're doing is using `echo` then yeah just use `echo {} {}` but I think OP did that as a easy demonstration. In our case, we're redirecting the output to a file and using `sh -c` did the trick perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use `-i` flag, which is the same as `-I{}` (it implies that the replacement is given with `{}`):

```
$ echo test | xargs -i echo {} {}
```

Comment: In the meantime: `This option is deprecated; use -I instead.` has been added to the manual `man xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

For me only the lower case works. I had hundreds of images in a directory and wanted to get them sources into a list. Upper case i `-I` option did not work for me. Only the lower case. Probably due to version differences. 
These images all had names like `Daniel_(somenumber).jpg`.

This syntax has worked :

```
ls -l | tr -s ' ' ':'| cut -d: -f9 | xargs -i echo "img src='"{}"'alt='{}'"
```

Returns:

```
src='Daniel_248.jpg' alt='Daniel_248.jpg'
...
```

Linux ver 4.14.96-hw+ #80 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I added some formatting to your answer to make it more readable. I hope I have correctly understood it.

Comment: I think there are at least 1 or 2 double quotes (`"`) missing at the end of the `echo` expression... FYI on macOS, I resorted to this simpler command: `ls -1 | xargs -I {} echo "img src='{}' alt='{}'"`